# Make org-delete-char (C-d) delete extra space after deleted word

Tags: org-mode, whitespace, deletion

Hitting `C-d` (`org-delete-char`) in an Emacs org file deletes the word following the cursor. I would like to delete the extra space left also without having to use `DEL`. I.e. one action to delete word and extra space.

Comment: documentation says, as function name suggests, that it deletes chars and insert spaces only in tables fields to keep the cells aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Despite that's not the documented behavior for `org-delete-char` which deletes only chars and no words adding spaces only inside table cells, you could achieve what you want doing either:

- defining a command which kills the next character if matchs `[:space:]` and rebinding it to <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>
- Adding `:after` advice to `org-delete-char` (vid. [advising functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html))

Looking `org-delete-char` implementation, taking a simplistic approach of just deleting the next blank character doesn't look like a good idea.